# Cual es la mejor manera para indexar en Elasticsearch, mediante logstash o con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

¿Cual es la mejor manera en cuanto rendimiento (uso de procesador, memoria, facilidad de uso) de indexar documentos en Elasticsearch, con logstash conectandose mediante el driver jdbc a MySql o mediante un script de PHP?

Aproximadamente son un millón de anuncios que entran a la base de datos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Con logstash puedes inyectar virtualmente cualquier dato a elasticsearch y está hecho para ese propósito justamente.

Comment: Y sabes si en cuanto a velocidad sea más rápido que un script en PHP ?

Comment: Es más rápido porque es un transporte propietario que no requiere de todo lo que php si... En teoría, la ejecución de un script php 1000 veces es menos eficiente que logstash que está "siempre vivo"